# CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0 xcode error

Tags: ios, uiimage, cgcontext

In my iOS App I am getting the following error:

```
CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
```

I think the problem comes from here:

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tanButton.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 6, 18, 6)];
```

This happened on a iPhone 5 running iOS7.

Does anyone knows how I can solve this?

Thanks,
Best Regards

Comment: What does your button do?

Comment: Does this happen only on iOS 7 targets? And if you comment this particular line, does the error go away? I ask because there are iOS 7 bugs that cause this sort of warning. Historically, this error is a result of calling Core Graphics functions outside of `drawRect` or a manually created `CGContextRef`, but there are `UIKit` controls in iOS 7 that erroneously generate this warning.

Comment: It is a button that calls a function to verify the state of some variables. If I change the button to this: UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tanButton.png"]; the problem is solved. But in this case I lose the style I want to achieve in the button.

Comment: This is on iOS 7, I did not test this in other targets, I will check it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. It was caused because when you make a resizableImageWithCapInsets It needs center pixels to generate a tiled image and if your image height is, for example 36, you should do: UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 6, 17, 6), to give at least one pixel to be tiled in the center of the image.